# AES decryption not working for more than 16 bytes

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am having a very strange problem using the AES encryption/decryption in Java. If I am encrypting/decrypting a string that is less then 16 bytes the cipher works fine but if I feed the cipher anything larger than 16 bytes I get the error "Given Final Block Not Padded Properly". I built some small code as an example:

```
package com.company;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Cipher aesEncrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            Cipher aesDecrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("ABCDEQWERTASDFGA".getBytes(), "AES");

            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);

            aesDecrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
            aesEncrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

            byte[] message = "Hello".getBytes();

            aesEncrypt.update(message);

            byte[] encrypted = aesEncrypt.doFinal();

            aesDecrypt.update(encrypted);

            byte[] decrypted = aesDecrypt.doFinal();

            System.out.println(new String(decrypted, "UTF-8"));
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When the byte[] message is "Hello" the encryption/decryption works fine but when I change it to "HelloMyBabyHelloMyDarling" it throws the exception. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: See [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29993/aes-cbc-padding-when-the-message-length-is-a-multiple-of-the-block-size) for some info on _padding_

Answer (score 4):

[`Cipher#update(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update%28byte[]%29) returns a `byte[]` which you're not using for some reason. You're simply throwing away everything except the last block (`Cipher#doFinal()` returns the last encrypted block after padding was applied). If your message only consists of a single block, then the ciphertext and the decrypted plaintext will be complete.

Since you're using short messages, then you don't need to use `Cipher#update` at all. Just use [`Cipher#doFinal(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28byte[]%29):

```
byte[] message = "Hello".getBytes();
byte[] encrypted = aesEncrypt.doFinal(message);
byte[] decrypted = aesDecrypt.doFinal(encrypted);
```

If you're trying to encrypt longer data (which might not fit into memory), then you should write the `Cipher#update` results to an OutputStream or use a CipherOutputStream without `update` or `doFinal` calls.